# Implementing some function in the background - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, production, dev-to-production, laravel-jetstream

I'm new to laravel and I got a question that is driving me crazy. I have a web application with laravel 8/jetstrean/taiwind css on a shared host and I need to run some specific functions o the background (like sending email whenever a user has been x months working in the platform). So I would like your help to know  how to do the following:

- Goal: execute code in the background without linking it to a middleware. (not after every HTTP  request)
- Have a log to see if there's any problem on running that code.

Any help would be very appreciated. thanks in advance...

Comment: did the answer below solve your issue?

Comment: haven't teste4d it, but as I read it sounds far more logic than I thought. I'll try it and let you know,  thanks

Comment: sure, please mark the below as the correct answer to help others with the same issue if it works for you, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at scheduling:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

You can create commands that are scheduled to run at the intervals you want.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan

If you write the logic in the command to check which users have been working x months, you can then send those users an email.

You will need to set up the scheduler to use a cron job.

The cron job will run the main Laravel scheduler, which then can run Console commands at different intervals.

The documentation explains how to do this.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

--

For bonus points, you can dispatch a Job, that sends the email

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#creating-jobs

Or you can trigger an Event and have a Listener that sends the emails

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events